# detect if input is hidden-type

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm selecting a element with a certain name

`$('[name="lol"]']`

but there can be two elements with the same name, one of the is a hidden input field.

How can I ignore hidden input fields from the selector above?

`$('[name="lol"]:not(:hidden)']` kind of works, but fails if the non-hidden input field is not visible on the screen... How can I specifically ignore only hidden-type inputs, not non-visible elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `<input type="hidden">` elements.  If so then look specifically for the `type="hidden"` attribute

```
$('[name="lol"][type!="hidden"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector instead

Answer (score 1):

Give them different id's and use that, rather than the name?